# plotting intervals calculated with python using sympy

Tags: python, sympy

For every parameter `alpha` (given in a list `listalpha`) I calculate the trace of a matrix `A`. Matrix `A` consists of a function `f` with variable `e` and `alpha`. I use sympy (`solveset`) to solve the inequality `trace<=4` with respect to parameter `e` and get a set of intervals for `e` satisfying the inequality e.g. `[(2 <= e) & (e < 4)]` for `listalpha[0]`. The results I also write in a list `resultlist`. So for every `alpha` in `listalpha` I get intervals for the parameter `e` written in `resultlist`.

```
for i in numpy.arange(0, len(listalpha)):
    A = numpy.array([[f(e, listalpha[i]), -1], [1, 0]])
    trace = abs(numpy.trace(A))
    result = solveset(trace <= 4, e)
    resultlist.append(result)
```

Now I would like to generate a plot `e(alpha)`, i.e. for every `alpha` I would like to draw the corresponding intervals of parameter `e`: E.g. the "alpha" as the x-axis and vertical lines corresponding to the intervals in `resultlist`.

Does anybody have some advice or a solution concerning this problem?

Comment: You can use `nums = [(i.left, i.right) for i in resultlist]` to get a list of interval numbers like `[(1, 2), (3, 4)]`. From there this is a plotting question and sympy isn't needed any more. With matplotlib there is the `axvline` function for vertical lines.

Comment: Thank you for the fast response! If I understand correctly this method is possible for one interval in the solution to get the boundaries of one interval and write them into a list. But what if for some parameter `alpha` the corresponding result consists of several intervals which are not connected (e.g. in `resultlist[4]` the result consists of several separate intervals each covering a finite range which do not intersect)? Is there also a possibility to extract a list of interval numbers in this case for every interval? Or is it possible to plot these intervals directly for every `alpha`?

Comment: If you have a union of intervals you can get the individual intervals using `resultlist[4].args`.